I can't copy and paste attachments directly from outlook to vb.net app
I have a "problem" with my code, I have a button with a function that pastes the documents on the user's clipboard to a list, the problem is when I try to directly copy and paste an Outlook attachment, but in my application the message that nothing is detected in the clipboard but instead I can paste that file anywhere in file explorer.
Is there a way through code to paste Outlook attachments?
thank you so much!
This is my function:
Private Sub btnPegar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPegar.Click
    ' Get clipboard data
    If Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

        Dim fileDropList As String() = CType(Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

        ' Variable to track whether at least one valid file has been found
        Dim archivoValidoEncontrado As Boolean = False

        ' Iterate over the list of files and do what you need with each one
        For Each filePath As String In fileDropList

            ' Get file extension
            Dim extensionActual As String = Path.GetExtension(filePath)

            ' Check if the file extension is one of those allowed
            If extensionActual.Equals(".PDF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".TIF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".JPG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".DOC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".DOCX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".XLS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".XLSX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".BMP", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".PNG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".GIF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".DOCUMSG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
               extensionActual.Equals(".MSG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

                'The file has an allowed extension
                archivoValidoEncontrado = True

                Try
                    ' Check if the file has already been added previously
                    If archivosAgregados.Contains(filePath) Then                        
                        MessageBox.Show($"The file '{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}' has already been added above.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    Else
                        ' Add the file to the list of added files
                        archivosAgregados.Add(filePath)

                        ' Get file information
                        Dim fileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)

                        ' Get the file size in KB
                        Dim fileSizeBytes As Long = fileInfo.Length
                        Dim fileSizeKB As Double = fileSizeBytes / 1024
                        Dim roundedFileSizeKB As Double = Math.Round(fileSizeKB, 2)

                        ' Add the file information to the ListView
                        Dim LI As ListViewItem = Me.lstFiles.Items.Add(filePath)
                        LI.StateImageIndex = 0
                        LI.SubItems.Add(roundedFileSizeKB.ToString() & " KB")
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show($"Error checking file '{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}': {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End If
        Next

        If lstFiles.Items.Count > 0 Then

            bProcesar.Enabled = True
            bEliminar.Enabled = True
        Else
            bProcesar.Enabled = False
            bEliminar.Enabled = False
        End If

        'All files do not match extension
        If Not archivoValidoEncontrado Then
            MsgBox("Extensions not allowed on the clipboard.")
        End If
        'There is nothing on the clipboard
    Else
        MsgBox("The clipboard does not contain files.")
    End If
End Sub

EDIT: responing to @dr.null this is my code with his answer:
Private Async Sub btnPegar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPegar.Click
    'Check if the clipboard contains file data
    If Clipboard.ContainsData("FileGroupDescriptor") Then
        'Get the names of Outlook clipboard attachments
        Dim attachedFileNames As List(Of String) = Await GetAttachedFileNamesFromClipboardAsync(Clipboard.GetDataObject())

        ' Variable to track whether at least one valid file has been found
        Dim archivoValidoEncontrado As Boolean = False

        ' Iterate over list of attachment names
        For Each fileName As String In attachedFileNames
            ' Check if the file extension is one of those allowed
            Dim extensionActual As String = Path.GetExtension(fileName)

            If extensionActual.Equals(".PDF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".TIF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".JPG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".DOC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".DOCX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".XLS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".XLSX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".BMP", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".PNG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".GIF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".DOCUMSG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse
           extensionActual.Equals(".MSG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

                'The file has an allowed extension
                archivoValidoEncontrado = True

                Try
                    Dim tempFilePath As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName)
                    Await SaveAttachmentFromClipboardToFileAsync(Clipboard.GetDataObject(), tempFilePath)

                    ' Check if the file has already been added previously
                    If lstFiles.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem)().Any(Function(item) item.Text = fileName) Then
                        ' Mostrar mensaje de aviso
                        MessageBox.Show($"The file '{Path.GetFileName(fileName)}' has already been added above.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    Else
                        ' Add the file to the file list
                        Dim LI As ListViewItem = Me.lstFiles.Items.Add(fileName)
                        LI.StateImageIndex = 0

                        ' Get the file size and add it to the file list
                        Dim fileSizeBytes As Long = New FileInfo(tempFilePath).Length
                        Dim fileSizeKB As Double = fileSizeBytes / 1024
                        Dim roundedFileSizeKB As Double = Math.Round(fileSizeKB, 2)
                        LI.SubItems.Add($"{roundedFileSizeKB} KB")

                        ' Add the file name to the list of added files
                        archivosAgregados.Add(fileName)
                    End If
                Catch ex As System.Exception
                    ' Handle the exception
                    MessageBox.Show($"Error checking file '{Path.GetFileName(fileName)}': {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End If
        Next

        'Enable the processing button if there are files
        If lstFiles.Items.Count > 0 Then
            bProcesar.Enabled = True
            bEliminar.Enabled = True
        Else
            bProcesar.Enabled = False
            bEliminar.Enabled = False
        End If

        If Not archivoValidoEncontrado Then
            MessageBox.Show("Extensions not allowed in the clipboard.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The clipboard does not contain attachments.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub

' Returns the names of the clipboard attachments
Private Async Function GetAttachedFileNamesFromClipboardAsync(clipboardData As IDataObject) As Task(Of List(Of String))
    Dim attachedFileNames As New List(Of String)()

    If Not clipboardData.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor") Then
        Return attachedFileNames
    End If

    Using descriptorStream As MemoryStream = TryCast(clipboardData.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor", True), MemoryStream)
        If descriptorStream IsNot Nothing Then
            Using streamReader As New StreamReader(descriptorStream)
                Dim streamContent As String = Await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync()
                Dim fileNames As String() = streamContent.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.NullChar}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                attachedFileNames.AddRange(fileNames.Skip(1))
            End Using
        End If
    End Using

    Return attachedFileNames
End Function

'Save the attached file to disk
Private Async Function SaveAttachmentFromClipboardToFileAsync(clipboardData As IDataObject, destinationFilePath As String) As Task
    If Not clipboardData.GetDataPresent("FileContents") Then
        Return
    End If

    Using attachedFileStream As MemoryStream = TryCast(clipboardData.GetData("FileContents", True), MemoryStream)
        Using destinationFileStream As FileStream = File.Open(destinationFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
            Await attachedFileStream.CopyToAsync(destinationFileStream)
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


Assuming that there really is no data, my guess would be that Windows is restricting access to that Clipboard data. Have you considered drag and drop? That said, what happens if you don't look for that data format specifically and check the Clipboard to see what formats are available? Is there still no data?

@jmcilhinney drag and drop did not work directly, what's more the app also works so you can paste or drag and drop, I had to install an office extension to be able to do that OutlookFileDrag my problem is mainly copying

@jmcilhinney answering the question "what happens if you don't look for that data format specifically and check the Clipboard to see what formats are available? Is there still no data?" If the clipboard does not contain a valid format, the message MsgBox("Extensions not allowed on the clipboard.") appears, but when trying to paste the copy of the Outlook attachment, the message MsgBox("The clipboard does not contain files.") appears. )

That doesn't even come close to answering the question I actually asked. I'm not asking what your code does if it doesn't find the specific format it's looking for. I'm asking what happens if you look to see what data is there and what formats it's available in. You'd have to change your code or specifically use the debugger to answer that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447388/14171304

@dr.null I have tried with the codes in the response and paste the name to the list but I do not get it in local or temp, and I need them since the function of the program is to insert metadata to the document that enters and generate a new one with the metadata to the final

@dr.null i edited the answer to show you my actual code

ah, one or more attachments. All right, can you benefit from this Article? There's a vb.net version in the comments. The data you get in the DragDrop event is the data you get from the Clipboard. Give it a try.

Your code assumes there is a real file link copied to the clipboard. That is not the case with Outlook attachments - attachments do not exist in the local file system, only in Outlook message store.
You need to process FileGroupDescriptor / FileContents clipboard formats.
